# How to debug command line utility in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I have C++ code in visual studio and an exe with pdb file, the exe is a command line utility.

I want to debug the executable. I cannot compile the source code in visual studio since it has a large no. of dependencies.

Is there a way where I can attach the debugger to debug the executable.

Comment: As I said I cannot compile the code due to external dependencies

Comment: You should be able to open the process using windbg which will break immediately once attached and debug that way, I know this isn't from visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

If it is compiled with VC++ then yes. Run your code, and attach the debugger from the menu: "Debug/Attach to process".

If you want to start the process with the debugger already attached, the follow this tutorial:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0bxe8ytt.aspx.

> To create an EXE project for an existing executable
>
> 1. On the **File** menu, click **Open** and select **Project**.
> 2. In the **Open Project** dialog box, click the drop-down list next to the **File name** box, and select **All Project Files**.
> 3. Locate the executable, and click **OK**.
>
>    This creates a temporary solution that contains the executable.

If yo did this, you can simply click on "Debug".

Comment: I cannot do that since there is no process, it just starts and ends in seconds. Its a command line utility as I said.

Comment: Ahh, ok I see your problem now. Then try this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0bxe8ytt.aspx. It should work!

Comment: @GáborAngyal: You should write that up in the answer.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Ok, I did it :)

Comment: Upvote for the effort. :) I think it could be Even Better™ with a description of the technique (it's just, open the executable in VS to create a temporary project for it). Still.